# How to put the Custom Transformer into the Transformer palette

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am trying to make a simple custom transformer so I have created a simple transformer as under:

[image]

How can I add it to the Transformer Palette:
[image]

The flow that I will do is a Http inbound endpoint -> My transformer -> Echo. What ever will be supplied should be appended with "Hello" by the custom transformer.

The purpose is to learn building a custom transformer.

Comment: The `homework` tag is obsolete.

Comment: thanks questions was drafted very nice and it solves my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to build Mule extensions (custom transformers, message processors...) that can be integrated in Studio's palettes, create them with [DevKit](http://docs-stg.mulesoft.com/anypoint-connector-devkit/v/3.8/).

Otherwise, to use your custom transformer directly in Studio, refer to it with a `Java Transformer`, as shown below:

[image: Java Custom Transformer]

Comment: Thanks @TimChild, I fixed the link.